# What is the data type of 'MyActivity.this' - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

well my question is that there aren't pointers in JAVA ...
but when we have to start another activity we do like this :

```
Intent in = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
startAcitivity(in);
```

So my question is that what is the data type of `MyActivity.this` ??

Comment: Did u try to debug and inspect its return type?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: It's not a data type, it's an instance of an Activity which is ultimately derived from Context.  The tree is Activity->ContextThemeWrapper->ContextWrapper->Context. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.  Java references are, in most circumstances, conceptually analogous with pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java pointers are not explicitly allowed,
However passing by reference(object) in Java is something which is implicitly based on pointer concept.

In your case, you are passing the context of parent class to child class,
which is actually passing by reference concept.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `MyActivity.this` is the same as writing `this`, **if** you are in a non-nested class, **or** to top-level class.

See this example:

```
public class TopLevel{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TopLevel().printClass();
    }

    public TopLevel(){
        new LowerLevel().printClass();
    }

    public void printClass(){
        System.out.println("Outer Class: ");
        // Will print something like "TopLevel.class"
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }

    public class LowerLevel{
        // This is a Nested-Class.

        public void printClass(){
            System.out.println("Nested Class: ");
            // Will print "TopLevel$LowerLevel.class"
            System.out.println(this.getClass());
            // Will print "TopLevel.class" again
            System.out.println(TopLevel.this.getClass());
        }
    }

}
```

Some using `this` in the nested-class does not reference to the same instance as when using it in the top-level class. Therefor, to get the "context" of the outer class in your nested class, you also specify the class you want the `this`-context from.