# What's the data type of a class name in android

Tags: java, android, methods, types, classname

I would like to ask, what is the data type of a class name? I already searched roughly for my problem but I couldn't find something that helped me.

I would like to write a method like this:

```
public void newActivity(???? oldClassName, ???? newClassName) {
    Intent in = new Intent(oldClassName.this, newClassName.class);
    startAcitivity(in);
}
```

I am not sure, what I should type into the '????'. Is such a method possible?
Thank you very much!

I found another question about a similar question, but didn't get it:
[What is the data type of 'MyActivity.this' - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292763/what-is-the-data-type-of-myactivity-this-android)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: That's `Class<T>`.  But your code cannot work.

Comment: "Is such a method possible?" -- no.

Comment: Why? Ia there another possibilty to do that? For me, it seems that it's not really senseful to write alwys those lines of code in example in an switch case?